# Globally change the font size in EPS figures (when using pdfLaTeX with pstool)

Tags: fonts, floats, pdftex, eps, psfrag

I have a document where float environments are typeset with \small font (tables, figures). For the tables and most environments in general, this works nicely with

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
```

thanks to the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/) package. However, it does not work for figures of the form

```
\begin{figure}
\psfragfig{path/to/some/figure}
\end{figure}
```

This is because I compile the document using pdfLaTeX and the [pstool](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstool) package. (What pstool does is to create an empty temporary document with only the EPS figure placed on the page without any figure environment. Then, this document is processed in multiple steps, until finally, a PDF file is produced, which is in turn then included as figure in my PDF document.)

So my question is: Is there a way to globally define the font size used in psfrag replacements without having to change the individual replacements?

For clarification, I do *not* want to do this:

```
\psfrag{marker}{\small replacement text}
```

I thought of somehow changing or inserting the figure environment into the temporary document by modifying one of pstool's macros or modifying the psfrag macro somehow, but I do not know enough about LaTeX to do it that way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.